# what's the meaning of "However touching may be an interest so tender"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "However touching may be an interest so tender" in this passage

Authorities . . . will tell us: ‘What is at the bottom the goal of your efforts, the
motive of your work, the object of your hopes? Is it not happiness? Well, this
happiness, let us act, and we will give it to you.’ No, Gentlemen, we will not let
you do it. **However touching may be an interest so tender**, we ask authority to
remain within its bounds. That authority limits itself to being just; we will occupy
ourselves about being happy

Answer (score 1):

The *interest so tender* is the supposed intention of providing happiness.

This is seen as a tender thing when e.g. a lover wants to make their beloved happy, but the author has doubts about the real intentions of authorities when it comes to providing happiness.

Touching is "touching the heart", that is, something very nice.

You could rephrase the sentence as:

> No matter how lovely it may be that the authorities want to be so kind as to give us that happiness, [...]